# Не удаётся правильно проэмулировать нажатие клавиши...

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток! Суть проблемы такова: нужно, чтоб каждую секунду нажималась клавиша Enter, пробовал через `keybd_event`, всё работает, но до тех пор, пока моё приложение является активным, а мне нужно, чтоб клавиша жалась постоянно, даже при свернутом приложении...

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сначала послать сообщение о нажатой кнопке, сделать маленькую паузу, потом сообщение о опушенной кнопке. А вообще, можно не морочится и использовать готовый [модуль](http://www.tt.rim.or.jp/~muramatu/delphi/SendKey/SENDKEY.PAS)

> > пока моё приложение является активным, а мне нужно, чтоб клавиша жалась постоянно

Проверьте, какому окну Вы сообщения шлете...

Answer (score 0):

```
SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
```

Comment: Не совсем точно....

Answer (score 0):

Делать это надо с последующим отпусканием клавиши, иначе клавиатура будет "ломаться".

```
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, 0), 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, 0), 0, 0); 
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // отпускание...
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```